# PHP: Recursively set array values to equal keys (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am taking over a large project, and a lot of nested arrays are defined for option select lists to be used with form_dropdown() and form_multiselect() in Codeigniter. However, these arrays simply have values set and not corresponding keys.

Here's an example:

```
$lists['roomItems'] = array('Private telephone','Television cable/satellite','Personal furniture/decorations','Computer','Radio');
$lists['busRoute'] = array('Yes','No');
$lists['transport'] = array('Medical appointments','Dental appointments','Dialysis center','Wound care center','Religious services',
                                'Shopping services');
```

What I'd like to do is recursively go through $lists and make the keys equivalent to the values. For a single array, I tried foreach($lists['roomItems'] as $key=>value) and tried setting the key equal to the value, but it didn't take.

Can anyone help? I have about 30 items in the $lists array plus other ones that I'd re-use this code, so simply manually changing the pointers isn't really something I'd like to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mhmmm what about:

```
$newList = array();
foreach($lists as $k=>$v) $newList[$k] = array_combine($v,$v);
```

should do the trick

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! It's array_combine() I totally forgot about.

Comment: ah i know that... i keep forgetting simple yet useful function all the time :D